# Does plotly-dash work on ipynb files in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am new dash and was wondering if there is a way to run dash on .ipynb files in vs-code. I found out that using `JupyterDash` you're able to run dash on Jupyter IDE (The web version). I was wondering if there is a way to extend this to .ipynb files in vs-code (I heavily use vs-code Jupyter instead of the web version).
I tried making a radio button using this code within a cell in a .ipynb file in vs-code and it didn't work (Of course the same code did work in Jupyter web version). If there is way to run it in vscode, please do let me know.

```
 from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash 
 import dash 
 import dash_core_components as dcc 
 import dash_html_components as HTML 
 from dash.dependencies import Input,Output 

 app = JupyterDash('SimpleExample')

 app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id = 'dropdown-color',
        options = [{'label' : c, 'value' : c.lower()} for c in ['Red','Green','Blue']],
        value = 'red'
    )
])
app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the latest jupyter dash documents. Try this:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = JupyterDash('SimpleExample')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id = 'dropdown-color',
        options = [{'label' : c, 'value' : c.lower()} for c in ['Red','Green','Blue']],
        value = 'red'
    )
]) 
# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

More about it here:
https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e